# Grammar error (subject-verb agreement) in Help

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the Help Center, on the [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) page, there's this block of text:

> Questions that you may ask:
>
> Using and administering official Ubuntu flavors including: Edubuntu,
>   Ubuntu GNOME, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Mythbuntu, Ubuntu
>   Studio, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Touch, and Ubuntu "Snappy" Core.
>
> Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
>
> Development on Ubuntu. Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical. Any
>   question not mentioned below or here are great!

That last sentence, `Any question not mentioned below or here are great!` is the issue. Either `question` should be plural, or `are` should be `is`. Right now, it's a conflict.

It's a minor issue, but can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done; thanks for spotting and reporting